# How do I turn off the one button control in offline Dynasty?

Tags: ncaa-football-11

I'm playing NCAA Football 11 on my Xbox 360. I want to control who I'm passing to not who the computer decides I should be passing to. Note I'm specifically asking about offline, not online dynasty.

I just would like to build my own team while running the team. Currently I cannot choose audibles or formation changes or nothing at the line.

Please if anybody could help me with this simple problem I would be appreciative.

Comment: Hi Donald, can you make your question a little more legible? There is some ranting going on that I believe is of no consequence to the question, and some additional punctuation and capitalization would help, too.